# Get file names list in a zip file withoutr unzipping

Tags: java, zip

I would like to have a way for my program to get the list of file names in a zip folder.

I'm verifying my inward and outward files list to ensure the delivery of the files. As the files are more in numbers, it takes lot of time to unzip and get the names list of a zip folder. I'm in windows environment.

Is there a way where I can get the list of file names that a zip folder contains, without unzipping it.

Comment: Yes. Please be more specific as to language you want to implement this in.

Comment: Thank you, I want this to be implemented in Java. Sorry I have not mentioned this.

Comment: Take a look at [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).

Comment: Thank you Elliott Frisch, I will try this.

Comment: the search keywords that I have used did not make a result to get this given link. Thanks for providing the link with answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this  documentation for Java zip built-in support

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html